# Updating day/night mode capable Android app to MaterialComponents theme, but getting incorrect theme error when inflating material widgets

Tags: android-widget, android-theme, material-components-android, android-night-mode

EDIT: On further inspection, it seems to be that only NightMode causes this crash, regardless of whether or not I am explicitly setting it myself, or letting Android's system wide setting take care of it!

I have an app that supports day/night mode using AppCompat theme. On startup, it applies either the day/night style from a stored setting (the user can update the setting at anytime from within the app as well).

To do so:

```
int mode = GlobalAppSettings.getStoredSettings().nightModeEnabled() ? AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES : AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO;
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);
```

I recently decided I wanted to use the Chip widget from material to implement tags, but when I the app tries to inflate a view with a Chip in it, I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The style on this component requires your app theme to be Theme.MaterialComponents (or a descendant).
```

I have updated my themes in my style to be derived from MaterialComponents, but nothing seemed to help. It still crashed. Then I commented out:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(mode);
```

And while the app is seemingly stuck in day mode, the Chip is now inflated correctly. Is the AppCompatDelegate method of forcing the day/night theme not compatible with MaterialComponents.DayNight theme?

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

My styles:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    
            <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_image</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar" />
        <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />
    
        <style name="EditText.Search" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
            <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black_overlay</item>
            <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black_overlay</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="GameyeToolbarTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/toolbar_title_color</item>
            <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/toolbar_title_text_size</item>
        </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just setting the theme on the Chip directly with

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents"
```

Which seems like it shouldn't be necessary given that my them derives from MaterialComponents. Maybe it's a bug in material?

I opened up a ticket on material to see if they had any ideas.
https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/1872